# How to have signal handler print time elapsed?

Tags: c, signals, sigaction, setitimer

I am writing a C program that has a sigaction handler. It also has a itimerval in case SIGALRM doesn't come in a while.

The handler should

1. print the total number of infinite loop completed
2. print the time elapsed
3. exit(1);

I noticed that signal handler doesn't take customized parameters, so I have a global loop counter.
My problem is: How do I get the time elapsed? Do I get that information from the timer? I am not completely understanding the usage of timer.
Also the code is printing 1 extra integer (from the loop) after the fprintf call before termination. How to fix that?

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/time.h>

int count = 0;

void handler (int code) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Reads completed: %d \n", count);
    exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    if (argc != 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: time_reads FILENAME TIMER\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Fail to open file\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    int i;
    srand(time(NULL));

    struct sigaction sa;
    sa.sa_handler = handler;
    sa.sa_flags = 0;
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sigaction(SIGALRM, &sa, NULL);

    struct itimerval timer;
    timer.it_value.tv_sec = strtol(argv[2], NULL, 10    );
    timer.it_value.tv_usec = 0;
    timer.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
    timer.it_interval.tv_usec = 0;

    if (setitimer(0, &timer, NULL) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Fail to set timer\n");
        exit(1);    
    }

    while(1) {
        fseek(fp, (rand() % 100) * sizeof(int), SEEK_SET);
        fread(&i, sizeof(int), 1, fp);
        printf("%d\n", i);
        count++;
    }

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note: You should not call printf() (and friends) from a signal handler. It is not signal safe.

Comment: @wildplasser Thanks for reminding that, but I have to call it since my assignment asked to do so.

Comment: Note that if the signal handler exits, the whole program exits.  If you want to do this more than once, you need the signal handler to return, not call `exit()`.  As to measuring elapsed time: record the start time; in the handler, find the current time; calculate and format the difference.

Answer (score 0):

In order to print the elapsed time, the handler must have access to the timer. A simple way to do this is to have the timer be a global variable too, just like the counter. For the extra integer being printed, this is because the signal interrupted the loop in the middle of the call to printf(). The printf() in the loop should be removed, as the total number of loop iterations will be printed by the signal handler.

Comment: The printf() in the loop should be removed? NO! That is just simply changing the purpose of the program.  Please consider that carefully before answering.

Comment: My mistake, looks like the printf() is needed for printing the data from the file. In this case, there is no way to prevent the handler from interrupting the main loop during the call to printf(). This will sometimes cause the final integer to be printed after the handler has already printed the time elapsed. An alternative approach would be to have the handler set a boolean, and have the loop exit gracefully when the boolean value changes. In this case the time elapsed would be printed by the main function, after the loop, before finally exiting.